# Receiving debt through PayPal attracts tax?

Tags: taxes, india, paypal

I reside in India, and one of my friend owes me a debt of 3 lakh rupees. Now the friend is living out of the country. He sent me the debt amount via PayPal. Is this acceptable? Will this credit to my bank account (via PayPal) cause me to owe income tax?

How can I declare a debt settlement non-taxable?